# ELIMINAR DECIMALES EN QUERY SEC_TO_TIME SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
Select Tecnico, SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(timediff(Hora_reporte, hora_llegada))) from reportes group by Tecnico;
```

Esto me devuelve resultados con microsegundos o decimales como el siguiente:
1:30:21.01656

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo elimino esos microsegundos o decimales que me regresa el query?

Comment: Podrias intentar añadiendo `ROUND(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(timediff(Hora_reporte, hora_llegada))),0)`. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta utilizando la funcion `TIME_FORMAT(valor,"%H:%i:%s")` de mysql en tu caso el valor seria el resultado de tu operacion

Ejemplo:

```
Select Tecnico, TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(timediff(Hora_reporte, hora_llegada))), "%H:%i:%s") from reportes group by Tecnico;
```